# DBMS Normalization

Tags: database, normalization

having this database.. 
requiring to identify partial and transitve dependencies...
and creating new tables for 3rd normal form..
i dunno if my answer is right but can someone pls help me?

this is the table..

```
member_num
member_name
member_address
member_city
member_zipcode
invite_num
invite_date
accept_date
dinner_date
dinner_attended
dinner_code
dinner_descript
entree_code
entree_descript
dessrt_code
dessert_descript
```

can you tell me if i am right in partial dependency..

```
member_num->member_name,member_add,member_city,member_zipcode.....
invite_num->invite_date,accept_date,dinner_date,dinner_attended...
dinner_code->dinner_descript..
entree_code->entree_descript...
dessert_code->dessert_descript..
```

i think i must create new attributes and tables to 3rd normal form.. but im so confuse about that..

Comment: give more context or delete that question. In order to identify relationships people need to understand, what those tables are there for (e.g. attributes, short description). E.g. why you would have a table member_num?